# How do I accumulate arrays into maps?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table `T` with columns:

```
cookie     string  
keywords   array<string>   
fqdn       string  
pixel      bigint
```

I want to write something like

```
select cookie, ???? from T group by cookie;
```

to get a table with columns

```
cookie     string  
keywords   map<string,int>   
fqdn       map<string,int>  
pixel      array<bigint>
```

where

- `cookie` is unique (guaranteed by `by cookie`)
- `keywords` counts how many times the keyword appeared in all arrays in the original table `T`
- `fqdn` counts how many times the domain appeared in all rows for the given cookie
- `pixel` counts how many times the pixel appeared in all rows for the given cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use the "vector" UDF's in Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ).  In Brickhouse, either an array or a map can be considered a "vector". For an array, the array index is considered the dimension, and the numeric value is considered the magnitude in that dimension.  For a map, we consider the string key as the "dimension" of the vector in a very large dimensional space, and the map value is the magnitude. ( This is for text-analysis type problems, similar to what it looks like you are doing).

Something like the following should work

```
SELECT cookie,
   union_vector_sum( keyword_map),
   union_vector_sum( map( fqdn, 1 ) ),
   collect_set( pixel)
FROM (
  SELECT cookie, fqdn, pixel,
         collect( keyword, 1 ) as keyword_map
  FROM T
  LATERAL VIEW explode( keywords ) k as keyword
  GROUP BY cookie, fqdn, pixel ) xk
GROUP BY cookie;
```

We probably should have new Map constructor UDF which takes an array and a single value, so we don't need that inner explode and collect. I don't think it will produce an additional map-reduce step in this form however.

There are some vector, and "bag of words" UDFs in Brickhouse now, we probably should add some more. Do you have any special requests ??

Comment: thanks. could you please publish then jar file? my hadoop server does not have maven.

Comment: in what form would you like me to specify my "special requests"? RFC?

Comment: @sds You can download prebuilt jars of brick house at https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Downloads . Make sure it is in your $HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH . If you have a bug or feature request, please file at https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/issues?state=open . We should be doing another release fairly soon.